keyword and function documentation for PostgreSQL using Emacs
I would like to get possibility to see inline documentation about functions and/or keywords used in SQL (PostgreSQL specifically) code. I know that I can call browser searching from inside Emacs but I would like just to read documentation inside Emacs. This is even enough for me to read info for a specific function/keyword.


Install sql or pgsql Mode for Emacs

Emacs comes with a built-in sql-mode that provides syntax highlighting and integration with databases, including PostgreSQL. If you want more PostgreSQL-specific features, you might consider third-party packages like pgsql mode.
Steps:
Enable sql-mode or pgsql-mode in Emacs when editing .sql files:
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\.sql\'" . sql-mode))
For PostgreSQL-specific customizations:
(setq sql-postgres-program "psql") ; Use PostgreSQL client

I know about sql-mode but the question is how to get pgsql documentation inside emacs? For example what I would like to get is ElPy for Python that shows documentation for python objects.
